# skype4comlib Create List of Friends

Tags: c#, skype4com

I'm trying to grab a list of all of my Skype friends who are online and put it into my `listbox` named `lst1`.
I'm also trying to make my tool answer to some commands like if some one sends `!news` to me it messages them a text that I've set in the code.

This is what I've tried so far, I'm just playing around with the code to learn how to use `skype4comlib`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Components;
using SKYPE4COMLib;
using System.Threading;

namespace betaskypetool
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroForm
    {
        #region Definitions
        Skype Merk = new Skype();
        private int count = 1;
        #endregion
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Merk.Attach(5, true);
                MessageBox.Show("You are now connected enjoy!", "Tutorial Skype Tool!");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed To Connect?\n Be Sure Skype Is Open!", "Tutorial Skype Tool!");
            }
        }

        private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusOnline;
        }

        private void metroButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusDoNotDisturb;
        }

        private void metroButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusAway;
        }

        private void metroButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusInvisible;
        }

        private void metroButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusOffline;
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                timer1.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusOnline;
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusAway;
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusDoNotDisturb;
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            this.Merk.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusInvisible;
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }

        private void metroButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(User spamall in Merk.Friends)
            {
                Merk.SendMessage(spamall.Handle, "Haiiiii" + spamall.FullName + ",\n" + richTextBox1.Text + "\n\n(cash) Sent From Merk's Tutorial Tool! (cash)");
            }
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I hope you understand my question and can help me out with what I need to do to add those 2 features to my project

Comment: I've just suggested an edit to clean up grammar for you, but I would suggest that this is really two questions, one that is about making a list of your online friends, and one that is making an automated response. You might consider splitting off the automated response part into a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection of your online friends like this:

```
var onlineFriends = Merk.Friends.Cast<User>().Where(u => u.OnlineStatus == TOnlineStatus.olsOnline);
```

After this it's easy to put them in a `ListBox`.

WPF example:

```
foreach (var friend in onlineFriends)
{
    MyListBox.Items.Add(friend.FullName);
}
```

That said, I'm not sure if it's worth to spend a lot of time learning it, because according to this blog post, Microsoft doesn't really support skype4comlib anymore.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12384/how-does-my-3rd-party-application-work-with-skype-and-how-will-changes-to-skype-impact-my-3rd-party-application

> As communicated in this blog post, due to technology improvements we are making to the Skype experience, some features of the API will stop working with Skype for desktop. For example, delivery of chat messages using the API will cease to work.

For example, I'm not able to send a message using the library anymore.
PS.: I'm using Skype 7.17.0.106